# Altova XMLSpy auto indent after XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, altova, xmlspy

what i did was to open a ABC.xml file and performing XSLT on it by pressing F10 in Altova XMLSpy. An XSL Output.xml is generated, and the results is pretty messed up, i.e. much of the code is in 1-2 lines as all tags are not indented automatically, and it's very hard to read. Is there a tool that i'm missing, or a function i'm not using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the xsl:output tag at the beginning of your XSLT (inside of xsl:stylesheet) and specify the desired output:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
```

The indent="yes" will improve the output - not everything on one line.